# Windows Phone 8 Camera - speed of image capture

Tags: c#, image, performance, camera, windows-phone-8

I'm looking for a way to increase the rate of image capture on my Lumia 920 phone.  I've done some tests and it seems that the image capture step takes around 1300 ms at full resolution (8 MP).  I've done a similar test with an iPhone 5 and the image capture step completed in less than 400 ms at full resolution (8 MP).  This is a big difference!  Here's my code:

```
public async Task TakePictures()
{
    IReadOnlyList<Windows.Foundation.Size> captureResolutions = PhotoCaptureDevice.GetAvailableCaptureResolutions(CameraSensorLocation.Back);
    PhotoCaptureDevice camera = await PhotoCaptureDevice.OpenAsync(CameraSensorLocation.Back, captureResolutions[0]);

    CameraCaptureSequence captureSequence = camera.CreateCaptureSequence(1);
    MemoryStream captureStream = new MemoryStream();
    captureSequence.Frames[0].CaptureStream = captureStream.AsOutputStream();
    await camera.PrepareCaptureSequenceAsync(captureSequence);

    StorageFolder localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;

    // take a bunch of images
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        TimeSpan t1 = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
        await captureSequence.StartCaptureAsync();
        TimeSpan t2 = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;

        // could save file here

        Debug.WriteLine("image capture time = {0} ms", t2.TotalMilliseconds - t1.TotalMilliseconds);
    }
}
```

Any ideas on why the `StartCaptureAsync()` method could be taking such a long time?  I've fixed parameters such as ISO, exposure time, focus, and white balance so the camera shouldn't need to recalibrate those settings for each shot.

One thing I thought of was using the native code API [described here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj571202%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), but I'm so new to Windows Phone development that I don't know much about doing that.

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: it's different hardware... perhaps the iPhone5 is just faster?

Comment: Any idea where the major time delay could be? Is it that the Windows Phone code just runs slower in general or perhaps it has to do with the actual hardware or Nokia's image processing chain?

Comment: Most likely it is the post-processing.  Lumia images end up being a bit smaller (filesize as jpg) than iPhone5 images (~2.56MB vs 3MB I've seen quoted for photos of the same scene/detail) and the sensor is actually about 10% larger (the 920 has ~300 more horizontal pixels).  It already has more work to do with the larger image and must be doing more filtering/compression to get the filesize down.  Your profiled times are around what one could expect of the hardware on these phones.  The raw image is ~24MB and figure even an i7 can manage maybe 500MB/s compression throughput...

Comment: At full resolution, for the iPhone 5 and Lumia 920, the file size and number of pixels are equivalent (both are 3224 x 2448), and the image sizes are similar as well.  The Lumia 920 does indeed have more pixels in the sensor, but I believe this is just because the 16:9 image format in the 920 uses a few of these "extra" pixels, so it shouldn't cause the delay I'm seeing.